# C# : serialPort reading new numbers each time

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino-uno

The problem is complicated, and my code is large, but let me try to explain it.

See the code below:

```
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("0800");  // Write to serial port for reading
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            serialPort1.Write("0800");  // Write to serial port for reading
            in_data = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            textBox7.Text = in_data;
            Console.WriteLine(in_data);
            in_data = "";
            serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
            serialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer();
        }
```

Let me explain it:
I implemented a button in C# form. When i press the button, it sends 0800 towards an arduino through serialPort1. It sends it two times. After each command sent, Arduino writes to serial port through  `Serial.println(receivedData, HEX)`. This data from Arduino is read by C#(the function above through `in_data = serialPort1.ReadLine()` line and is displayed in textBox7. In last of the function, I am clearing both buffers.
The problem however is, whenever I am pressing this button, some new data is being display in textbox.

And I don't understand the reason, because the circuit connected to arduino should always respond with same code. I have tested the circuit with other fixtures, and otherwise that circuit is working fine.
Writing into serialport is working just fine. For example this function:

```
 private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("EXTADC");  // Write to serial port
            Console.WriteLine("EXTADC");
        }
```

Please note: sending two commands each time is necessary in order to get the desired output from the circuit. Also, I am pretty new to Arduino and C# (you might be having an idea from my post).

Comment: It's difficult to say, when we don't know what the expected response is. What does 0800 do? And why do you need to send it twice? Maybe a serial port monitor helps you to see whats happening on the port. There are some free ones available to download.

Comment: You are reading data before you clear buffers. Or which "button" you press in *"whenever I am pressing this button, some new data is being display in textbox"*? Is it `button13` or some other you didn't show?

Comment: What return character is Arduino returning at the end of each line?  Is it '\n' or '\r'?  The ReadLine expects the '\n'.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(1);` <= Whenever you find this in an event handler, you should see an imaginary red flag and hear an imaginary siren go off.

Comment: @d4zed thanks for reply. I used a parallel Arduino serial monitor and reply from Arduino is perfect. 0800 is a command to read a register with address 08 and replay should be 08--(here -- is the contents of register)

Comment: @TRoa, so the reply should be 08--, and the reply is perfect, then where does "some new data" come from? You should see in the monitor program what data is send and correlate this to your textbox. What happens, when you send 0800 only once? You shouldn't need this command twice, do you?